# Installing conda on Colab

Tags: conda, google-colaboratory

I want to install a library on colab to use GPU capabilities. This library can only be installed via conda. How to do this without getting errors such as: File "/usr/local/bin/conda, line 7, in  from conda.cli import main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'. Thanks

Comment: What library are you trying to install? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem? (There's not enough information in the original question to provide meaningful suggestions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example how to install faiss using conda.

```py
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
# can change to another channel or package
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local -c pytorch faiss-cpu
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
import faiss
```